# layout problems with CSS position

Tags: html, css

hey guys i'm trying to create a navigation system similar to the one you can find on starbucks.com. Here is the link to my sample: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73992/js_tests/test.htm I am accomplishing the effect with navigation sample on the bottom but as you can see there are positioning problems. You can find the CSS in the source code. I figured this is the best way to test it. Thank you in advance for any help I can get it.

as per the suggestion  here's the css

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#nav
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-left:3em;
}   

#nav ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}

#nav ul li
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
}    

#nav ul li ul li
{
    margin-top:0px;
}

#nav ul li h1
{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#F7FF88;
    border:solid 5px black;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:none;
    z-index:20;
}

.content
{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#F7FF88;
    border:solid 5px black;
}

.content form
{
    display:block;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
} 

.content p
{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}   

.gallery
{
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:solid 1px black;
} 

.gallery img
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 5px 10px 0px;
    float:left;
} 

/*
This next section is identical but represents what happens w/ the absolute positioning.
*/

.content2
{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#F7FF88;
    border:solid 5px black;
    top:30px;
    z-index:-5;
} 

.content2 form
{
    display:block;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
} 

.content2 p
{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```

if this helps this is what I am trying to accomplish

[image: this is an example of the off hover(on) and then active when the section is clicked if i could get the css working the functionality would be easy... just can't seem to get these accomplished.]

Comment: You are always better off making a test case and posting the code/markup in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. Change the position from absolute to relative, and remove the 30px top margin. You should be able to get the same effect as the 3 examples above yours.

```
.content2
{
    position: relative;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#F7FF88;
    border:solid 5px black;
    z-index:-5;
}
```

[EDIT]

First off, remove the "border-bottom:none;" so your h1 will still have bottom borders for that tabbed effect.

```
#nav ul li h1
{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#F7FF88;
    border:solid 5px black;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    z-index:20;
}
```

Give your h1 a class, let's say "tabbed"

```
<li><h1 class="tabbed">Ex. 1</h1>
```

And probably use some negatives for your CSS.

```
h1.tabbed {
    position:absolute;
    top:-28px;   
}
```

Give this one a try.

Comment: the problem with this is that it lines up perfectly with the bottom of the top tab. I need the h1 to cover the content div a little bit to create the illusion of a tabbed thing.

Comment: Just saw the example you posted. No need to remove "border-bottom:none;" if that's the case. @Brodie

Comment: this works but it poses a new problem http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73992/js_tests/test.htm < they still overlap. Would it work if I changed around the original li structure at all?

Comment: @Brodie Just give your "#nav ul li ul li" in your CSS a suitable margin-bottom. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put `display:inline;` on `li`

And `float:left;` on `ul`

I think it's your big problem, if I had understand well your problem.

Comment: this lines them up, I'm having more of a problem w/ the h1's interacting w/ the content divs. I need the h1's to overlap the content divs by a few pixels to create the illusion of a tab.

Answer (score 0):

**float : left** can solve your positioning problem. You have to add just two lines in your css

```
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```